# Probability of getting two heads in k tosses

Tags: probability

You toss a fair coin until you get a total of two heads. What is the probability that you made
k tosses?

My answer was $P(2h, K) = Pr_{2}^K/Vr_{2}^K$
$P(2h, K) = \frac{P_{K}}{(K-2)!2!}/2^k$
$P(2h, K) = \frac{K!}{(K-2)!2!}/2^k$

But the teacher told me it was wrong. What am I not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer isn't quite right, as the teacher wants the probability that you got the second head on toss $k$. You worked out the probability that among the first $k$ tosses, exactly two are heads.

---

To solve the question, just note that

- The $k$-th toss must be heads, which has probability $1/2$.
- Exactly one of the first $k-1$ throws is heads.

The latter event has probability $(k-1)\cdot(1/2)^{k-1}$, so the final answer is $\frac{k-1}{2^k}$.

Comment: Man, your answer is not very clear to me, (k-1) (1/2)^k-1 is not equal to (k-1)/2^k, is equal to (k-1)/2^k-1 and why you do that operation, the multiplication?

Comment: @Alex100 multiply by $1/2$ for the probability of the first bullet point. You need both of the first and second bullet points to happen -- since the events are independent, you can just multiply the probabilities.